# Matlab matrix save 1 positions for large matrices

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix

I have a sparse matrix in Matlab. I would like to save the positions of 1's in the matrix row-wise and column-wise.

For example consider the below matrix:

```
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

I would like two files written as:
row-wise.csv:

```
1,2
1,4
2,4
4,3
5,1
```

column-wise.csv:

```
5,1
1,2
4,3
1,4
2,4
```

I know I can run a loop row-wise or column-wise and save element by element using fprintf, but is there a better way?
I'm dealing with very large matrices and I'm wondering what an efficient way is to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to perform this task. Then to write them out to a csv file, you can simply use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html).

For the column-wise, you can use the two outputs of `find` which are the row index and column index of each 1 (in column-major order).

```
data = [0 1 0 1 0
        0 0 0 1 0
        0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 1 0 0
        1 0 0 0 0];

[row, col] = find(data);
M = [row, col];
dlmwrite('column-wise.csv', M);
```

Then to obtain the row-wise result, you can just sort your column-wise result by rows and then columns using [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html).

```
dlmwrite('row-wise.csv', sortrows(M))
```

The alternative to this, is to perform `find` again on the transpose of your data (to force row-major ordering) but I would think that the `sortrows` approach is faster.

```
[col, row] = find(data.');
dlmwrite('row-wise.csv', [row, col])
```

Comment: Thank you!! As soon as I posted the question, I realized I spoke too soon! Thanks anyway.